# POODLE kills tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, poodle-attack

We have a web app running on Apache tomcat 7.0.56 on windows, and we are using IE to access it. Tomcat is running secured over HTTPS

On one system, after running our app and closing IE, when we restart IE, we cannot fetch any pages from the tomcat server, not even the tomcat home page. If we restart tomcat, the issue disappears until we close thr browser again.

Tom cat has been configured to protect against the POODLE attack. If we disable the security fix (I.e. re-enable SSL v3), everything works fine.

Is there something we can do to get tomcat working with the POODLE security fix?